# Using XML attributes in Applescript

Tags: xml, applescript

So I recently found out about [XML-Parsing in Applescript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WorkwithXML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH67-SW1). I wanted to parse an XML file that had a structure like this:

```xml
<example>
    <sample value="hello world"/>
</example>
```

So I tried something like this:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell XML file "/path/to/the/file.xml"
        tell XML element "example"
            return XML attribute "value" of XML element "sample"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

However, the error says:

```
System Events got an error: Can’t get XML element "example" of XML file "~/Desktop/xml.xml" number -1728.
```

According to MacErrors.h `number -1728` means `errAENoSuchObject`, so no such object was found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you’re reading the right file? The error message suggests xml.xml doesn’t have a root element named “example”. Try `get name of every XML element of XML file "~/Desktop/xml.xml"` to see.

Comment: @foo Doesn't work. I have now learned an important thing though: Never work with files in Applescript.

Comment: FWIW, if you’re working with large or complex XML documents, you can also use Foundation’s `NSXML` classes via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge. The ObjC API’s a bit more complex, but is faster than using System Events and supports more powerful XPath queries.

Comment: What doesn’t work? Be sure to enclose that `get` command in a `tell app "System Events"` block, e.g. `tell app "System Events" to get name of every XML element of XML file "~/Desktop/xml.xml"`. Referencing files is a mess in AppleScript, but in this case you’re dealing with the System Events app so just give it a valid POSIX path string to your XML file. If can’t find the file it’ll tell you, e.g. “System Events got an error: Can’t get XML file "~/tesst.xml".” number -1728. Your error message indicates it found the file okay, but can’t find the root `<example>…</example>` element within it.

Comment: @foo Just pasting the entire thing you provided here results in an error `number -1703`, which means some data is in the wrong type.

Comment: The above line works here: `tell application "System Events" to get name of every XML element of XML file "~/Desktop/xml.xml" --> {"example"}`. However, if `xml.xml` is not a valid XML file then System Events does throw -1703 (the accompanying error message is entirely unhelpful). I recommend you validate your `xml.xml` file, e.g. using HTML Tidy: `tidy -xml ~/Desktop/xml.xml`.

Comment: @foo It works now, I probably had the wrong quotation marks.

Comment: I'm sure there was a _Thank You_ in there somewhere for you, @foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it:

```applescript
return XML attribute "value" of XML element "sample"
```

Should be:

```applescript
return the value of XML attribute "value" of XML element "sample"
```

This works for me:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell XML file "/path/to/the/file.xml"
        tell XML element "example"
            return the value of XML attribute "value" of XML element "sample"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

---

In **Terminal**:

```
% file foobar.xml
foobar.xml: XML 1.0 document text, ASCII text
% cat foobar.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<example>
    <sample value="hello world"/>
</example>
%
```

In **Script Editor**:

[image]